# Can temporarily suspended users award bounties they offered while not suspended?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Can temporarily suspended users award bounties they offered while not suspended (just in case you're wondering, I'm not suspended, I answered a question by a suspended user). Will someone get the bounty?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I speak to what I suspect, rather than what I know. I do not think that they can award the bounty. But the reputation for the bounty is already up. I bet that at the end of the bounty-period, the answer with the highest number of votes (as long as it has at least 2 votes) will receive the bounty. If there is no such answer, the bounty will not be awarded. If there is a tie... good question. Maybe FGITW gets it. But again, this is all just speculation.

Comment: [A related meta.SO question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100050)

Comment: It's a bizarre situation anyway: The user got suspended, presumably for posting problems from an ongoing contest. The questions are all closed, except the one that has a bounty, which can't be closed. The [question you answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/367473/49437) is is Problem B. 4538 from [KöMaL](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=honap&h=201304&t=mat&l=en).

Comment: Is this a good idea to provide a complete proof to a question from a contest due May 10, 2013?

Comment: I didn't realize that, I presumed it was an old contest question, should I delete my solution?

Comment: If people would close unsourced, no-effort-shown questions, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @JohnMarty: Probably not, [unless the contest organizers ask for it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6764). The user who asked the question has already seen your answer; deleting it at this point would just help them cover their tracks. If you want to be helpful, though, e-mail the organizers and let them know about the question. (Someone _probably_ already did that, given that the user was suspended, but it won't hurt to make sure.)